# Cannot access Object/Array data in PHP function without getting error

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am currently working on a project with PHP, JavaScript and jQuery and have come across an issue.  I am trying to get the PHP function getCountryBorders() to return just the polygon information for a country but I cannot seem to access object data with object['property'] as it gives me the

**Fatal error**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php(10): getCountryBorders('BS') #1 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php** on line **21**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

server.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if(isset($_POST['iso_a2'])) {
            $iso_a2 = $_POST['iso_a2'];
        }

        switch($action) {
            case 'populateSelect' : populateSelect();break;
            case 'getCountryBorders' : getCountryBorders($iso_a2);break;
        };
    };

    function populateSelect() {
        $data = file_get_contents('../../data.json');
        echo $data;
    }

    function getCountryBorders($iso_a2) {
        $data = file_get_contents('../../data.json');
        echo $data['features'];
    }
?>



//index.js
$('#document').ready(() => {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'libs/php/server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'populateSelect'
        },
        success: (result) => {
            result['features'].forEach((country) => {
                $("<option>", {
                    value: country.properties.iso_a2,
                    text: country.properties.name
                }).appendTo('#countries');
            })
        }
    });
});

$('#countries').change(() => {
    console.log($('#countries').val());
});

$('#test').click(() => {
    alert('Clicked')
    $.ajax({
        url: 'libs/php/server.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'getCountryBorders',
            iso_a2: $('#countries').val()
        },
        success: (result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is within the $('#test') ajax function.

Thank you,

Liam

I have tried looking at network responses but they just return

**Fatal error**: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php(10): getCountryBorders('BS') #1 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php** on line **21**

Comment: You need to decode the JSON first with `json_decode()`

Comment: @MosheGross, I tried that and I got the same error but it said Object instead of String

Comment: @MosheGross it gives me a  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error

Comment: You have to use the `->` to access property items like `$object->property` instead of `$object["property"]` or pass true as the second argument of json_decode to convert it to an array

Comment: @MosheGross Thank you, that seemed to have solved the issue but it now says Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\worldmap\libs\php\server.php on line 22
Array.  Would I need to run this through a loop to create a new array?

Comment: Perhaps `echo json_encode($object->property)`

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it fixed.  I used that and it worked fine